# TextView inside FrameLayout being cut-off and not wrapping

Tags: android, android-layout

Ive got a `FrameLayout` which im dynamically adding `TextViews` to. Currently, the TextViews near the edge arent wrapping at the end of the parent FrameLayout and are going off screen. The FrameLayout is using `wrap_content` for both the width and height:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/wrappingFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        >
```

The `TextViews` are just being created, then translated to a certain spot using `.setTranslationX()` and `.setTranslationY()`.

I've tried getting it to wrap using some answers found elsewhere on SO, such as setting LayoutParams to WRAP_CONTENT on the TextView:

```
newTextView.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

I've also tried `newTextView.setSingleLine(false);` but that didnt work either.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** So I noticed that none of the dynamically added views respond to any methods on them except things like color/textsize. I tried calling methods like `setMinLines(3)` and `.setWidth(100)` and they had no effect.

Comment: Why is your frame layout height and width using wrap_content? If you dont want the contents within the frame to go off screen wouldnt it be a better idea to set a definite width and height, or even match parent for both?

Comment: @YawAsare its wrapping an ImageView which has a dynamic size. Changing the FrameLayout to match_parent doesnt seem to fix the text issue anyway.

Comment: Can you post the full code of your xml file?

Comment: @YawAsare This whole thing is wrapped in another FrameLayout which is also wrap_content. Thats irrelevant though.

Comment: You should set match_parent for wrappingFrameLayout width if it is contained within another frame-layout/layout

Comment: @RaViMete The other framelayout that `wrappingFrameLayout` was contained in was also `wrap_content`. Setting `wrappingFrameLayout` and/or the container framelayout width to `match_parent` doesnt solve the issue.

Comment: pls post the whole xml and dynamically created code to help u further

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `FrameLayout.MarginLayoutParams` instead of `.setTranslationX()` and `.setTranslationY()` to position the `TextViews`.

Something like:

```
FrameLayout.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.MarginLayoutParams)textView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.leftMargin = xPosition;
layoutParams.topMargin = yPosition;
textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

(I was having the opposite problem. The `TextViews` were wrapping but I wanted them to be cut-off. I was using the `LayoutParams` and margins. Changing to `setTranslation` fixed it for me.)